# How can traversing through a (bit-)map be implemented more elegantly?

Tags: java, arrays, bitmap, offset, traversal

In general: How can traversal offsets be implemented and used more efficiently?

Let's say we have a bitmap defined below. How could we traverse through (in this case collect) all nearby pixels starting from a fixed pixel - and ultimately avoid these 8 if-statements?

```
// The bitmap 1920x1080px
RGBColor[][] imageMatrix = new RGBColor[1920][1080];

// Collect all nearby pixels that are not white
ArrayList<RGBColor> neighboringPixels = new ArrayList<RGBColor>();

// Width-index of center pixel
int w = 50;
// Height-index of center pixel
int h = 50;

// Initializing offsets for a more elegant check-up...
int[][] offsets = { { -1, -1 }, { 0, -1 }, { 1, -1 },
        { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 0, 1 }, { -1, 1 },
        { -1, 0 } };

// But this is what I came up with
// Get top-left pixel
if (!(w - 1 < 0 || w - 1 > 255 || h - 1 < 0 || h - 1 > 255)) {
    neighboringPixels.add(imageMatrix[w - 1][h - 1]);
}
// Get top pixel
if (!(w < 0 || w > 255 || h - 1 < 0 || h - 1 > 255)) {
    neighboringPixels.add(imageMatrix[w][h - 1]);
}
// Get top-right pixel
if (!(w + 1 < 0 || w + 1 > 255 || h - 1 < 0 || h - 1 > 255)) {
    neighboringPixels.add(imageMatrix[w + 1][h - 1]);
}
// Get right pixel
if (!(w + 1 < 0 || w + 1 > 255 || h < 0 || h > 255)) {
    neighboringPixels.add(imageMatrix[w + 1][h]);
}
// Get bottom-right pixel
if (!(w + 1 < 0 || w + 1 > 255 || h + 1 < 0 || h + 1 > 255)) {
    neighboringPixels.add(imageMatrix[w + 1][h + 1]);
}
// Get bottom pixel
if (!(w < 0 || w > 255 || h + 1 < 0 || h + 1 > 255)) {
    neighboringPixels.add(imageMatrix[w][h + 1]);
}
// Get bottom-left pixel
if (!(w - 1 < 0 || w - 1 > 255 || h + 1 < 0 || h + 1 > 255)) {
    neighboringPixels.add(imageMatrix[w - 1][h + 1]);
}
// Get left pixel
if (!(w - 1 < 0 || w - 1 > 255 || h < 0 || h > 255)) {
    neighboringPixels.add(imageMatrix[w - 1][h]);
}
```

Comment: define "efficient"? do you mean speed or lines of code?

Comment: @Lashane I primarily mean just lines of code. There has to be a way to avoid those 8 if-statements or even 26 if-statements should we work in a three-dimensional room.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are iterating on a 3x3 square:

```
for (int i=w-1; i<w+2; ++i) {
   if (i<0 || i>=255) continue;
   for (int j=h-1; j<h+3; ++j) {
       if (j<0 || j>=255) continue;
       if (i==w && j==h) continue;
       neighboringPixels.add(imageMatrix[i][j]);
   }
```

write the code as simple as you can and let the compiler make the optimization.

Comment: it is almost correct code, just change `if (i==0 && j==0) continue;` to use w/h instead of `0`

Answer (score 0):

You current code contains 32 conditions in worst case.

More or less minimal solution in terms of lines of code I come to is like this:

```
final int minH = Math.max(0, h - 1);
final int maxH = Math.min(255, h + 1);
final int minW = Math.max(0, w - 1);
final int maxW = Math.min(255, w + 1);

for (int i = minH; i <= maxH; i++)
    for (int j = minW; j <= maxW; j++)
        if ((i != h) || (j != w))
            neighboringPixels.add(imageMatrix[i][j]);
```

In worst case there will be 4+4*4*2 = 36 conditions.

Minimal solution in terms of execution time could look like this:

```
final int prevH = h - 1;
final int minW = Math.max(0, w - 1);
final int nextH = h + 1;
final int maxW = Math.min(255, w + 1);

if ((prevH >= 0) && (prevH <= 255))
    for (int i = minW; i <= maxW; i++)
        neighboringPixels.add(imageMatrix[prevH][i]);
if ((h >= 0) && (h <= 255)) {
    if ( (minW != w) && (minW <= 255) )
        neighboringPixels.add(imageMatrix[h][minW]);
    if ( (maxW != w) && (maxW >= 0) )
        neighboringPixels.add(imageMatrix[h][maxW]);
}
if ((nextH >= 0) && (nextH <= 255))
    for (int i = minW; i <= maxW; i++)
        neighboringPixels.add(imageMatrix[nextH][i]);
```

Worst case 2+2+4+6+2+4 = 20 conditions

As further optimization:

Condition `if ( (a>=0) && (a<=255) )` could be optimized to `if ( (a&~0xff) != 0)` but it works only for `[0-255]` range

Answer (score -1):

Simply:

```
for (int i = -1 ; i <= 1 ; i++) {
    int wi = w + i;
    if (wi >= 0 && wi <= 255) {
        for (int j = -1 ; j <= 1 ; j++) {
            int hj = h + j;
            if (!(i == 0 && j == 0) && hj >= 0 && hj <= 255) {
                neighboringPixels.add(imageMatrix[wj][hj]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```